# helm how to use the checksum/config inside the helper function for a whole Opaque Secret which contains a config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a need where my helm chart structure looks like.

```
apache-template
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── _stateful-set.yaml
│   ├── configmap-bootstrap.yaml
│   ├── configmap-auth-generate.yaml
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   ├── secret-conf.yaml
│   ├── service.yaml
│   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   └── statefulset.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

I have this `_stateful-set.yaml` file being rendered and included based on the args being passed from main `statefulset.yaml`.

I have a snippet in my helper chart `_stateful-set.yaml`

```
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secret.yaml") . }}
{{- $btcSecret := include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secret.yaml") . | sha256sum -}}
```

I am unable to get this `include` working in `_stateful-set.yaml`. Any help ?

One last question is , Would the template itself is valid in this repo ?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure this out myself.

First thing we can have as many _*tpl or yaml files in the templates , helm will pick it up just fine.

BasePath I was able to fix by doing below in _helpers.yaml and just include it in the main sts template.

```
{{- define "btc.checksumTemplate" -}}
{{- $btcSecret := include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secret.yaml") . | fromYaml -}}
{{ print $btcSecret | sha256sum }}
{{- end -}}
```